# Tricky SQLite query, could use some assistance

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, inner-join

I have a rather confusing **SQLite** query that I can't seem to quite wrap my brain around.

I have the following four tables:

### Table "S"

```
sID (string/guid)  | sNum (integer)
-----------------------------------
aaa-aaa                   1
bbb-bbb                   2
ccc-ccc                   3
ddd-ddd                   4
eee-eee                   5
fff-fff                   6
ggg-ggg                   7
```

### Table "T"

```
tID (string/guid) | ... other stuff
-----------------------------------
000
www
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

### Table "S2TMap"

```
sID    |    tID
-------------------
aaa-aaa    000
bbb-bbb    000
ccc-ccc    xxx
ddd-ddd    yyy
eee-eee    www
fff-fff    000
ggg-ggg    000
```

### Table "temp"

```
oldID (string/guid) | newID (string/guid)
------------------------------------------
   dont care          fff-fff
   dont care          ggg-ggg
   dont care          zzz
```

What I need is to be able to get the MAX() sNum that exists in a specified "t" if the sID doesn't exist in the temp.NewID table.

**For example**, given the T '000', '000' has S 'aaa-aaa', 'bbb-bbb', 'fff-fff', and 'ggg-ggg' mapped to it. However, both 'fff-fff' and 'ggg-ggg' exist in the TEMP table, which means I need to only look at 'aaa-aaa' and 'bbb-bbb'. Thus, the statement would return **"2"**.

---

How would I go about doing this?

I was thinking something along the lines of the following for selecting s that don't exist in the "temp" table, but I'm not sure how to get the max of the seat and only do it based on a specific 't'

```
SELECT s.sID, s.sNum FROM s WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT newID from temp where tmp.newID = s.sID)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select max(s.sNum) result from s2tmap st
join s on st.sId = s.sId
where st.tId = '000' and not exists (
  select * from temp
  where temp.newId = st.sId)
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/26124/9) to play with.

Another option, probably less efficient would be:

```
select max(s.sNum) result from s2tmap st
join s on st.sId = s.sId
where st.tId = '000' and st.sId not in (
  select newId from temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just had to join on S2TMap and then to T in order to restrict the result set to a given T.

```
SELECT MAX(s.sNum)
FROM s
    INNER JOIN S2TMap m on m.sID = s.sID
    INNER JOIN t on t.tID = m.tID
WHERE t.tID = '000'
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT newID FROM temp WHERE temp.newID = s.sID
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query should give you a list of Ts and their max sNums (as long as all exist in S and S2TMap):

```
SELECT t.tID, MAX(sNum)
FROM S s
JOIN S2TMap map on s.sID=map.sID
JOIN T t on map.tId=t.tID
LEFT JOIN temp tmp on s.sID=tmp.newID
WHERE tmp.newID IS NULL
```